# pandas vectorized operation to get the length of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, string-length

I have a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Donald Dump','Make America Great Again!','Donald Shrimp'],
                   columns=['text'])
```

What I like to have is another column in Dataframe which has the length of the strings in the 'text' column.

For above example, it would be

```
                        text  text_length
0                Donald Dump           11
1  Make America Great Again!           25
2              Donald Shrimp           13
```

I know I can loop through it and get the length but is there any way to vectorize this operation? I have few million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the `apply` method of the DataFrame.
With this method you can manipulate the data any way you want.

You could do something like:

```
df['text_ength'] = df['text'].apply(len)
```

to create a new column with the data you want.

**Edit** After seeing @jezrael answer I was curious and decided to timeit.
I created a DataFrame full with lorem ipsum sentences (101000 rows) and the difference is quite small. For me I got:

```
In [59]: %timeit df['text_length'] = (df.text.str.len())
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit df['text_length'] = df['text'].apply(len)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the timing. Interesting to see apply is faster than inbuilt str.len!

Comment: the problem with apply aside from not being idiomatic is that this will not work on NaN values ; stick to the string methods

Answer (score 6):

Use [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
print (df.text.str.len())                   
0    11
1    25
2    13
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['Donald Dump','Make America Great Again!','Donald Shrimp'],
                   columns=['text'])
print (df)
                        text
0                Donald Dump
1  Make America Great Again!
2              Donald Shrimp

df['text_length'] = (df.text.str.len())                   
print (df)
                        text  text_length
0                Donald Dump           11
1  Make America Great Again!           25
2              Donald Shrimp           13
```